# html 5 query on auto text size

Tags: html, css, web

my problem is all about adjusting the text size according to viewport screen resoulution so that the text will not come in two lines..
for example visit http://www.asti.inetsavy.com/rushi/

here, when you open that link,right click to know the source code.

and my css 
file can be downloaded when you click on index.css from the above link
if you cannot download it from there download it from here

https://www.mediafire.com/?jh2q3e9dfmpvsyq

if the viewport screen resolution is different then,the top left images(home,and other two) comes in the next line and also, the navigation menu comes in two lines.
so please let me know the solution

in my screen the text is good as you view in 1600*900
but in case of other resolution the user have to resize or zoom out to adjust according to his resolution.

Comment: Provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Well, then use media queries to adjust the font-size. And btw., IMHO that design has much bigger problems than font sizes … ouh, it hurts my eyes. Quick, find tab close button … ah, better.

Comment: can you please list put the problems you saw

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check CSS media queries, it's what you need

Example:

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    p {
       font-size: 13px;
    }
}
```

This will resize the text to 13px only on smartphones

[Mozilla article on Media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion..i learnt that i need to do something with the media queries but i am unaware of implementation it either in html or in css documents

Comment: Try this:

Add this to your <head> section in your html
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">`

After that add the above code to your CSS file, it should then shrink the text to 13 pixels when you resize your browser window.